# "Class HelloController not found" error on composer autoload config with psr4

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader, psr-4

I try to create my own composer library. I've chose to use psr4 for autoloading mechanism. It works fine with the library project but something goes wrong when I add this library to another project as dependency. I expect the library project create an instance of a class which is located in main project. However this class cannot be found by composer autoloader.

My library project source is here : https://github.com/brnogz/kwinsey

My example project which uses this library like that(HelloWorld class is located in controller/HelloWorld.php file) : https://gist.github.com/brnogz/e27a1dd40ba00b818b23fe7ab8815fad

Comment: State the exact error message, and be more specific about the code example you use. Currently you expect anyone trying to help to digest a whole uncommon MVP framework in one go. For debugging, add `require` to explicitly execute the code that you suspect cannot be autoloaded, and see if it works. One thing: `"psr-4":{ "kwinsey\\":"/" }` looks suspicious. Why "/", the correct path would be "." or "".

Comment: @Sven you're right. when i fixed the path with "/", it began to work. thank you

Comment: @Sven  also sorry to bad question

Answer (score 0):

Please move all your sources to a `src` subfolder and use `"src/"` as the PSR-4 target folder. Autoloading from a project root folder is pretty much undefined behaviour.

Comment: i made it like that because i've not used test yet, but i'll convert the structure as you said